# How to access an element in a Numpy array

Tags: python, list, numpy

So I have this list of Numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array    

m = [array([0,  64]), array([ 0,  79]), array([0,  165]), array([0,  50])]
```

How do I index the number 50 from the m[3] element in the array?

Comment: @ojy Wow I didn't think that would work. That was too simple it slipped my mind. Thanks!

Comment: It would probably make more sense for these to be a 2D array, rather than a list of 1D arrays. You might want to have a read of [this](http://www.sam.math.ethz.ch/~raoulb/teaching/PythonTutorial/intro_numpy.html).

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned in the other comments, if your intention is to use a 2D-array, you should create it as:

```
m = array([[0, 64], [0, 79], [0, 165], [0, 50]])
```

and then access the elements like:

```
print(m[3, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is actually accessed like normal python lists:

```
 m[3][1]
```

Comment: For a proper multidimensional array (rather than just a list of 1D arrays as in your example), this sort of 'chained' indexing will still work, but it's generally faster and easier to use a tuple of indices inside the square brackets. See [the docs here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) for more info on indexing multidimensional arrays.